# YII : How to Change datetime format displayed on the View

Tags: php, datetime, view, model, yii

A newbie question in Yii:
I have a model of a table in Yii that contain a datetime field.

I'm using CActiveForm to display this field:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'createdon'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'createdon', array('id'=>'createdon')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'createdon'); ?>
</div>
```

but the textfield displayed is on datetime format come from MySQL which is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

How could I change the format displayed on the textfield to a different time format?
(maybe dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy or else)

any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want the date stored in one format, but displayed in another format (i.e. multiple views), then consider changing it in the model.

For example:

```
class Whatever extends CActiveRecord    
{
    protected function afterFind ()
    {
            // convert to display format
        $this->createdon = strtotime ($this->createdon);
        $this->createdon = date ('m/d/Y', $this->createdon);

        parent::afterFind ();
    }

    protected function beforeValidate ()
    {
            // convert to storage format
        $this->createdon = strtotime ($this->createdon);
        $this->createdon = date ('Y-m-d', $this->createdon);

        return parent::beforeValidate ();
    }
}
```

Which methods you override depends on what you're trying to achieve.

[From the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#customization):

> 9. Customization  CActiveRecord provides a few placeholder methods
>      that can be overridden in child classes to customize its workflow.
>
>    - beforeValidate and afterValidate: these are invoked before and after
>        validation is performed.
>    - beforeSave and afterSave: these are invoked
>        before and after saving an AR instance.
>    - beforeDelete and afterDelete:
>        these are invoked before and after an AR instance is deleted.
>    - afterConstruct: this is invoked for every AR instance created using
>        the new operator.
>    - beforeFind: this is invoked before an AR finder is
>        used to perform a query (e.g. find(), findAll()).
>    - afterFind: this is
>        invoked after every AR instance created as a result of query.

Comment: hey... thanks, the afterFind() method is the one I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
class SomeClass extends CActiveRecord
{

    protected function afterFind()
    {
        // convert to display format
        $this->my_date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->my_date_time)->format('d-m-Y');

        parent::afterFind();
    }

    protected function beforeSave()
    {
        // convert to storage format
        $this->my_date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $this->my_date_time)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use [`CDateFormatter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter) and it's method [`format`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#format-detail)

OR you could use native PHP's way to format date using function [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

I think there are lots of examples in `PHP` manual on formatting options (as well as explanation of what each format modifier mean), so it wouldn't be a problem to figure things out, but if you have any problems with Yii's `CDateFormatter`, I can give you some examples.

Comment: where should I format the value before displayed it on the form?
could I use something like this:
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,date('d-m-Y','createdon'), array('id'=>'createdon')); ?> ??
or is there any event or behaviors on yii model where I can do it?

Comment: Basically you want your date to be formatted due to locale (you can set locale using [`CLocale`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLocale)). I pass `CDateFormatter` in my view - this doesn't bother me much. If your project is localized for your area and you don't consider to localize it to other areas, you can go with `date('d-m-Y',<timestamp>)` (Yii just offer you a tool - to use it or not is a matter of your choice). It's more convenient to use [`CDateFormatter`] in tandem with [`CLocale`] otherwise.

Comment: "or is there any event or behaviors on yii model where I can do it?". I didn't, but I think you can attach a behavior.