# Yii DOB formatting on update

Tags: php, yii, date-format, date-formatting, date

wondering if anyone can help.

I have a DOB field in my database that my form is populating. We've done a bit of work to make it a bit more UX friendly and make sure we get the date of birth in the correct format, however, when i then go to update the form, it's not reinterpreting the DOB field.

Here's my code;

Model

```
public $year;
public $month;
public $day;
```

Model -> rules()

```
array('day','length', 'max'=>2),
array('day','length', 'min'=>2),
array('day', 'numerical','integerOnly' => true, 'min' => 1 ),
array('year','length', 'max'=>4),
array('year','numerical','integerOnly' => true, 'min' => 4),


protected function afterFind() {    
    $dob = explode('/', $this->dob);
    $this->year = $dob[0];
    $this->month = $dob[1];
    $this->day = $dob[2];            

    parent::afterFind();
   }
```

Model -> added to beforesave()

```
$this->dob = $this->year .'/'. $this->month .'/'. $this->day;
```

And in the view _Form

```
echo $form->textFieldGroup(
  $user, 
  'day', 
  array(
    'widgetOptions' => array(
      'htmlOptions' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'DD')
  )
)) ;
echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
    $user,
   'month',
   array(
       'widgetOptions' => array(
          'data' => array('01' => 'January' , '02' => 'February' , '03' => 'March' , '04' => 'April' , '05' => 'May' , '06' => 'June' , '07' =>'July' , '08' =>'August' , '09' =>'September' , '10' =>'October' , '11' =>'November' , '12' =>'December'),
        // 'data' => 'Jan','Feb';
          'htmlOptions' => array(
            'class' => 'col-md-3 ',
            'prompt' => 'Choose month',
          ),
       )
   )
 );
 echo $form->textFieldGroup(
  $user, 
  'year', 
  array(
    'widgetOptions' => array(
      'htmlOptions' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'YYYY',
        'class' => 'col-md-3',
      )
)
));
```

Same view obviously for the update, but i need something for the actionUpdate to explode the data and put it back into the drop downs

Does anyone have any ideas on the easiest way to do this?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811706/yii-how-to-change-datetime-format-displayed-on-the-view

Comment: I can't see what i'm doing differently. I seems the afterFind() is what explodes the dob field back out into it's original values, but it's not doing anything

Comment: have you added beforevalidate function to frame `dob` variable in `y-m-d` format?

Comment: Is that not just to store the file in the DB correctly - i'm already doing this via beforeSave()? Just to confirm, the functionality i have already exists and works fine on create, stores the data in the correct format, it's just the update that it isn't exploding the data

Comment: ok got it now, you want to explode it after validate if some validation error occurred? is it?

Comment: Hi, no, not quite. So actionCreate works just fine, my 3 values implode into 1 value which submits to the database just fine. No issue at all with create, no validation required.

However, when i then go to update that record (actionUpdate) all i get is the full dob field in the year, i need this dob field exploded and inserted into the date/month/year fields. This is what i believe the afterFind() is supposed to be doing, but it's not

Comment: well in that case can you tell me what is the output of `$dob = explode('/', $this->dob);`, because it should work as expected.. i am not able to see any error in it

Comment: with a DB value of '1982-01-12', the code above explodes the following:
Array ( [0] => 1982-01-12 )

Comment: I've answered my own question, wasn't until i put the last comment up, i realised my mistake, i was exploding with the separator '/', but the separators were stored as '-', so it couldn't explode anything

Thanks for your help @ChetanAmeta, appreciate it